# Parse date from _table_suffix

Tags: sql, date, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I want parse date from _table_suffix for execute last date in table names, but i can't to do it.
Firstly, i select just like [image]

After parsed dates me saw a mistake about parse string with '..x' in the end.
[image]

What function will be solve for problem ? Where are from '...x' ???

I maybe can select max date from all tables, but each table can have next day after report day in name of table. So i want solve problem only with table suffix.

Comment: Are you sure that no table suffix contain a X? did you check all the table suffix?

Comment: Like guillaume said, easiest explanation is that you have an "x" in your data. Do you have any influence on the table design? If something is a date it should be stored as a date to bypass this problem completely.

Comment: yes, i forgot about table that special note with 'x' in the end, i delete this table and now this is working
big thanks!:)

Comment: @Error_2646 thanks for attention, i did fool mistake)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]
I delete table with '...x' and can check my query. So, u can try check last table_suffix in your wildcards =)